# Call a GET API each XX seconds, and put the JSON response in a CSV

Tags: javascript, json, arrays

I'm a newbie, and I apologize for this. 
I am writing a script that will make a GET request. The result is a JSON array and the best deal would be to have it put automatically in a CSV/TXT file.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: BASE_URL,
beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));
},
success: function(jimmi) {
// Output the results
if (typeof jimmi === "string") {
station = JSON.parse(jimmi);
}             
var ar_len = jimmi.length
for (i=0; i < ar_len;) {
$("#results").html(
"Station: " + jimmi[i].name + "<br />")  
i++     
}
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('Error');
}
});
```

My problems:
* I get displayed only the last element of the array, and I can't figure out why.
* I would need to make this call automatically each 5 seconds
* The JSON results should be written into a CSV/TXT file.

Can someone help me?
BTW, the URL is https://its.navizon.com/api/v1/sites/1001/stations/ and you can log using demo@navizon.com - no password (read only)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're changing the contents of `#results` for each element of `jimmi` by changing the entire inner HTML. So in the end, only the last element gets displayed. You need to use `append` instead. To make the call every 5 seconds, use the `setTimeout` method. Something this like:

```
function makeCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: BASE_URL,
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));
        },
        success: function(jimmi) {
            // Output the results
            if (typeof jimmi === "string") {
                jimmi = JSON.parse(jimmi);
            }

            for (i=0; i < jimmi.length; i++) {
                $("#results").append("Station: " + jimmi[i].name + "<br />");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });

    window.setTimeout(makeCall, 5000);
}

makeCall();
```

**Note:** The line `station = JSON.parse(jimmi);` is not useful because the variable `station` is never used. I changed it to something that made more sense.